# Algebraic Derivation of Feynman-Heaviside formula for retarded electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

We want to do the algebra to start from the equation of a retarded electric field until we obtain the Feynman-Heaviside equation, however, by doing the algebra of each of the following two terms and substituting in the equation, we obtain the Feynman-Heaviside relation with some extra terms

Is there something wrong in the algebra?

The marked expression is the Feynman-Heaviside formula.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Also, please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Feynman-Heaviside formula contains total time derivatives instead of partial time derivatives... this may be an issue as the partial derivative of R is c (from t' = t - R/c) while the total time derivative of R is just the radial velocity. By R I mean the magnitude of the position vector.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/423650)